# How to clone DOM SVG element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, copy, htmlcollection

I want to store multiple HTMLCollection in an array but I don't want them to be dynamic.

```
var history = [];
var mysvg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

this.saveToHistory = function(){
  history.push(mysvg);
}
```

For now, in my array `history`, the `mysvg` is a dynamic HTMLcollection. `history[0]` will be the same than `history[1]` even if when i called `saveToHistory()` `history[0]` was different from `history[1]`

I think making a copy of `mysvg` before pushing it in `history` is the way to solve this... but how can I do this?

Comment: This is somewhat unclear, is the problem that `getElementsByTagName` returns a live nodeList, if so use `querySelector` instead. Explain why `history[0]` would be the same as `history[1]` etc ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm drawing SVG in a canvas. Everytime I draw a SVG,  i call `saveToHistory()`. Because mysvg is dynamic, `history[0]` is the same than `history[1]` but I dont want them to be... `querySelector` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: So you're just saving the canvas element, and think you'll get whatever is drawn in the canvas at that point in time ?

Comment: Yes, because when im storing the innerHTML instead of the HTMLcollection, I can see that the innerHTML is static and is showing what I want. @adeneo

Comment: Sure it is, but you can't reasonably expect to store just the canvas DOM node, and get it's contents at any point in time, you actually have to get the HTML for that.

Comment: so what is my alternative here? because basically what I'm trying to do is a undo/redo function but with only using dom elements. The innerHTML worked, but it's deleting the events so I'm trying to find something else... @adeneo

Comment: I really don't know how you'd store the state of the canvas without just saving the SVG elements, i.e. the HTML, it contains.